# How to access array list in Json by php?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am currently working with Accessing json using php in wordpress. I have successfully decoded the json but when i try to access the values it doesn't fetch . I am trying to access the Cluster_ID and Image
values.
Here's my api link http://ec2-13-127-149-66.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/api/news
[image]

I have tried the following code:

```
<?php

/**

 *Plugin Name: plugin two
 
 **/
function myjson8(){
    $request = wp_remote_get( 'http://ec2-13-127-149-66.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/api/news' );

if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
    return false; // Bail early
}

$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );

$data = json_decode( $body );

if( ! empty( $data) ) {
    foreach( $data  as $product ) {
        echo $product->Cluster_ID;
        foreach($data->data as $news){
            echo $news->Image;
        }
}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking the data from the news feed that you supplied then placing it in a JSON viewer you get:

[image: Base structure]

On opening level 0 we get

[image: Level 0]

This is not what you want so we need to look at level 1 and its structure

[image: Level 1 structure]

So your code would be:

```
for($x=0; $x<count($data[1]); $x++ ) {
  $clusterId = $data[1][$x]['Cluster_ID'];
  for( $p=0; $p<count( $data[1][$x]['data'] ); $p++ ) {
    $pic =  $data[1][$x]['data'][$p];
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello@jeff please look at this question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66415847/how-to-access-json-fields-by-using-php>